# Webpack exclude third-party common css from .vue component

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, css-loader, vue-loader

I have a vuejs component that's pulling in a common scss lib. In the final built css, I don't want to include any common css files. I just want to include css classed I wrote in the component. here is the example:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">{{message}}</div>
  <div class="class-from-common-css-lib"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '../node_modules/common-sass/dist/lib';
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

How can I make webpack to build a style file that only contains:

```
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

here is my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: '[name].build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'css-loader'
                },
                {
                  loader: 'sass-loader'
                }
              ],
              fallback: 'vue-style-loader',
            }),
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        exclude: /app/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "[name].styles.css",
    }),
  ])
}
```

Comment: What does your webpack config look like for vue-loader? also do you even need the @import if you don't want anything from it..?

Comment: sorry, I would say that i need this common css in one of the elment in the component.